# Run string as Code

Tags: vb6

How to call an existing VB6 function and pass parameters or execute a statement utilizing some defined objects dynamically? E.g.

```
Private Const KONST = 123.45
Private Function First()
    Dim var1 As String
    Dim var2 As Date
    Dim var3 As Integer
    ...
    var3 = Second(var1)                 'LINE 1
    ...
    var2 = var2 + IIf(var3 > KONST, 1, -1) 'LINE 2
    ...
    var2 = var2 * KONST                 'LINE 3
    ...
End Function

Private Function Second(ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Second = CInt(str)
End Function
```

At line 1: Name of the function `Second` could be dynamic while using `var1` and returning value

At line 2: The whole `IIf` should be dynamic using `var3` and `KONST`

At line 3: Whole `var2 * KONST` should be dynamic i.e. here i may write `var2 + KONST` or `var3 / KONST` or `var3 + 222` or `1 + 2` or `myCollection.Item("item_Key")`.

All such dynamic configuration will be in a config file.

**Edit**

I am trying to make grid layout and data population dynamic. By grid layout i mean number of columns, their title, order, format, etc. And by population i mean loading data into the grid, in doing so, sometimes we resolve a database value with some of our Enums, we apply some logic on data before showing it, value of one column is based on value of other column, etc. Though, upto some extent, this can be achieved via databases views, but to have all such logic in a central location we do such things from source code. Therefore i need some way to call my vb6 code dynamically and define the calling (function name, parameters, enums, types, statement) in a config file.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify two things: 1. What do you want to send in? 2. What do you want to get back?

Comment: Your questions seems a bit vague. I think you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use `CallByName` (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186143 for one of many easily found examples) to invoke methods and properties on an object dynamically.

But I think you want entire composed statements to be executed dynamically.  For that you can use the Script control (as in VBScript).  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184740 for a sample.  In particular, it has a `Eval` function that runs arbitrary statements.